# Coincidir con una coma o un punto y coma. ¿Y por qué el error en ^(,|;){1}$?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy tratando de buscar variables, lo hago con regex.

Mi primera regex hace algo como:

- Empieza con var,
- luego pueden repetirse espacios 1 o más veces,
- seguido de 1 o más letras,

y hasta ahí me funciona bien.

El **problema** es que estaba buscando algo para hacer un `XOR` en regex. ¿Por qué necesitaría eso? Porque una variable puede ser:

`var a, b` o `var a;` por lo que solo se debe cumplir o `a,` o `a;` , por eso una disyunción exclusiva (XOR).

Lo que encontré fué: `^(,|;){1}$`, aunque me sirve si solo tengo una coma y un punto y coma, pero NO me sirve si está todo junto osea, `var a`, o `var a;`

Además de mi problema, ¿por qué a ese regex le agregan `^` y `$`, por qué el patrón se conforma de esa manera?

```js
(function(){
 var text = "var a, b;"
 var regex = /var\s+[a-z]+/ig;
 if(regex.test(text)) console.log(text.match(regex));
})();

var newRegex = /var\s+[a-z]+(^(,|;){1}$)0/ig;
if(newRegex.test("var a,b;")) console.log("Done");
```

Comment: El resultado esperado es `var a,` o `var a;`? ¿Por qué no [`/var\s+[-\w]+\s*[,;]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/RsWKR8/1)?

Comment: O sea, creo que son temas que ya estaban respondidos en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/117171/127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `var a,` o `var a;` por lo que solo se debe cumplir o `a,` o `a;`

Fácil, la clase de caracteres `[,;]` coincide con 1 solo caracter: una coma o un punto y coma.

```
/var\s+[-\w]+\s*[,;]/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3UpJC8/1/)

---

> algo para hacer un `XOR` en regex

Por cómo funciona el motor de expresiones regulares, no hay diferencia entre un `OR` y un `XOR`. Hay que tener en cuenta que coincide con un subpatrón o con otro (o con ninguno), por lo que no tenemos un caso en el cual un `XOR` aplicaría... Quizás si esa estructura estuviese repetida con un cuantificador, pero ahí ya sería otro caso.

En fin, si fuese un `OR` para más de un caracter, donde no podemos usar una clase de caracteres,

```
(?:subpatrón1|subpatrón2)
```

---

> Lo que encontré fue: `^(,|;){1}$`
>
> [...] Además de mi problema, por qué a ese regex le agregan `^` y `$`

No sé por qué está con `^` y `$` (habrá que preguntarle al autor), probablemente porque sea una respuesta a cómo coincidir con una coma o un punto y coma como único caracter en el texto, pero **está mal** usarlo dentro de tu patrón sin sacarle el `^` y el `$`.

Además, el `{1}` no tiene sentido, es totalmente innecesario. `(,|;){1}` es lo mismo que `(,|;)`.

Y por último, evitaría crear grupos innecesarios, quedando: `(?:,|;)`.

Pero, de nuevo, esto tiene sentido para más de 1 caracter. Si es un único caracter, es muchísimo más eficiente y sencillo de leer como:

```
[,;]
```

Comment: Gracias Mariano, aprenderé aún más acerca de los grupos !

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Esta va de yapa: https://regex101.com/r/3UpJC8/2 (sólo funciona en [navegadores modernos](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags))

Comment: wow, intentaré estudiarlo y así aprender más, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Con una pequeña corrección: https://regex101.com/r/3UpJC8/3 y demo en https://jsfiddle.net/marianom/0g2u2ymc/ (no acepta `,` ni `;` entre comillas dentro del valor de una variable, pero eso te queda como tarea :-))

Comment: (no está optimizada, tiene varias cosas para mejorar, pero era para darte una idea del tipo de solución delo que creo que estás buscando)